# Flutter yandex map init causes "Unable to instantiate activity"

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, yandex-mapkit

Fatal Exception on adding yandex mapkit to project:

Empty Flutter project.
Add yandex_mapkit: ^3.1.1 in pubspec.yaml.

Init yandex_mapkit, by pub.dev instuction: https://pub.dev/packages/yandex_mapkit

When run main.dart:

> Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... √  Built
> build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk. Installing
> build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk... E/AndroidRuntime(17681):
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime(17681): Process:
> com.example.test_yandex_map, PID: 17681 E/AndroidRuntime(17681):
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.test_yandex_map/com.example.test_yandex_map.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
> "com.example.test_yandex_map.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip
> file
> "/data/app/com.example.test_yandex_map-dpNzlkJVGKi1iBVn_qHZTA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.test_yandex_map-dpNzlkJVGKi1iBVn_qHZTA==/lib/x86,
> /data/app/com.example.test_yandex_map-dpNzlkJVGKi1iBVn_qHZTA==/base.apk!/lib/x86,
> /system/lib]] E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2843)
> E/AndroidRuntime(17681):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
> E/AndroidRuntime(17681):  at
> android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
> E/AndroidRuntime(17681):  at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
> E/AndroidRuntime(17681):  at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
> E/AndroidRuntime(17681):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
> E/AndroidRuntime(17681):  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> E/AndroidRuntime(17681):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
> E/AndroidRuntime(17681):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
> E/AndroidRuntime(17681):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
> Method) E/AndroidRuntime(17681):  at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> E/AndroidRuntime(17681):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
> E/AndroidRuntime(17681): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> Didn't find class "com.example.test_yandex_map.MainActivity" on path:
> DexPathList[[zip file
> "/data/app/com.example.test_yandex_map-dpNzlkJVGKi1iBVn_qHZTA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.test_yandex_map-dpNzlkJVGKi1iBVn_qHZTA==/lib/x86,
> /data/app/com.example.test_yandex_map-dpNzlkJVGKi1iBVn_qHZTA==/base.apk!/lib/x86,
> /system/lib]] E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    at
> dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
> E/AndroidRuntime(17681):  at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
> E/AndroidRuntime(17681):  at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
> E/AndroidRuntime(17681):  at
> android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
> E/AndroidRuntime(17681):  at
> androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
> E/AndroidRuntime(17681):  at
> android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1215)
> E/AndroidRuntime(17681):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)
> E/AndroidRuntime(17681):  ... 11 more

Flutter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1556], locale ru-RU)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.7)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
```

• No issues found!

Files modified, due yandex maps initialization:

...src/build.gradle

SDK < 21 throws exception, so I set it to 21.

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.test_yandex_map"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }



dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.yandex.android:maps.mobile:4.2.0-full'
}
```

...main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test_yandex_map">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
   <application
```

...kotlin/.../MainActivity

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import com.yandex.mapkit.MapKitFactory

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        MapKitFactory.setLocale("YOUR_LOCALE") // Your preferred language. Not required, defaults to system language
        MapKitFactory.setApiKey("YOUR_API_KEY") // Your generated API key
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    }
}
```

Comment: I just accedently remove this... Bruh
package com.example.my_app_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just accedently remove this:
kotlin/.../MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.my_app_name
```